# Cloned DateTime changes value

Tags: php, symfony

I have a value, a DateTime that I clone and without touching it in a foreach I display it again. But without any clue the value has changed. I know it's from the:

`if ($rtt->getPrttDateDebutPose()<$conge->getCngDateDebut() || $poseRTTService->getDateLastDay($rtt)>$conge->getCngDateFin()) {`

Because I tested it, it's what can possibly change the value (even though I can't figure why either). But a clone ? Why would it change I don't do anything with it ?

Here's the complete code :

```
$end_rtt = clone end($RTT_pris);
var_dump($end_rtt); // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Algo that allows to separate in two arrays the conges w/ rtt and those w/o
foreach ($conges as $conge) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($RTT_pris as $rtt) {
        if ($rtt->getPrttDateDebutPose()<$conge->getCngDateDebut() || $poseRTTService->getDateLastDay($rtt)>$conge->getCngDateFin()) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if ($count == count($RTT_pris) && !in_array($conge, $conges_final)) {
       array_push($conges_final, $conge);
    } else {
        array_push($conges_w_rtt, $conge);
    }
}
var_dump($end_rtt); // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here's the output of the two `var_dump($end_rtt)` :

[image]

See how the date pass from 11 to 20.

If anyone understands that, do please explain.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/clone): `When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references.`

Comment: try to convert the date (change the format or tostring )

Comment: I did that from the documentation especially to avoid any link. I also tried to copy the list, and same result, this particular date is changing.
And I need the object, not the date.

Comment: Yes, because it's still a reference to the same DateTime as is in the final element of your array. I'm not sure you understood the docs. This is how clone works. If you need something different, you need to implement your own __clone method.

Comment: Well I guess not then. Still don't know how it's possible. because I never change the value. Will do, if I can figure it out

Comment: Well, what do the `getPrttDateDebutPose` and `getDateLastDay` methods do? Do they change the date object?

Comment: The first one is just the regular get for the value of the object. And the second one creates new RTT and returns one, just returns, I don't change any object. I tried `$this->prttDateDebutPose = clone $this->prttDateDebutPose;` in my own clone method but it says that DateTime is no object. **Edit** : Got it with a `if`. Thanks